# Page is not redirecting to the login page while using Authorization Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I have created an AuthorizationFilter to check authorization while accessing action methods. The code is below:

```
public class MyAuthorizeActionFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly int _userAge;

    public MyAuthorizeActionFilter(int userAge)
    {
        _userAge = userAge;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        bool isAuthorized = CheckUserPermission(context.HttpContext.User, _userAge);

        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }

    private bool CheckUserPermission(ClaimsPrincipal user, int age)
    {
        if (user.Claims == null || !user.Claims.Any()) 
            return false;

        var dob = Convert.ToDateTime(user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth).Value);

        var years = DateTime.Today.Year - dob.Year;

        return years >= age;

    }
}
```

Then I have created an Authorize Attribute, which is below:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public MyAuthorizeAttribute(int age) : base(typeof(MyAuthorizeActionFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { age };
    }
}
```

I used the above authorize attribute in my controller action method.

```
[MyAuthorize(21)]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Now the problem is when unauthorize, the system doesn't redirect to the login page. Though I put the below code in ConfigureService method in the startup class.

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "_auth";
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
                options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/account/logout");
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/account/login");
            });
```

Can any body help me to redirect to the login page when the page is unauthorize.

Comment: It’s already included in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OnAuthorization after checking the authorization, we can redirect to the account/login page with below code.

```
context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/account/login");
```

OR

```
context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new
                    {
                        controller = "account",
                        action = "login"
                    }));
```